# The reduce function causing errors

Tags: javascript, angular, store, rxjs, ngrx

The errors shown in the chrome console:

```
1. http://localhost:3000/vendor/@ngrx/store/index.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

2. localhost/:19 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found)
loading http://localhost:3000/vendor/@ngrx/store/index.js(…)
(anonymous function) @ localhost/:19
```

reducer.ts: 
*I cant find the aproppiate types for something1 return value's type and state type.

```
import { Action} from '@ngrx/store';
export const something1 = (state: any = {}, action:Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

main.ts:  **Removing "provideStore({something1})" will cause the app work**

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';
import {AccountService} from "./account.service";
import {provideStore} from '@ngrx/store';
import {something1} from "./reducer";

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  AccountService,
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
  provideForms(),
  provideStore({something1})
])
  .catch((err: any) => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I changed in systemjs.config.js inside map the value of '@ngrx' from vendor/@ngrx to 'node_modules/@ngrx'.